# Why might Respawn be wiping my entire database?

Tags: c#

I am setting up subcutaneous tests, following a similar paradigm as outlined [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/10/24/vertical-slice-test-fixtures-for-mediatr-and-asp-net-core/). Calling [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/respawn)'s Reset is wiping my entire database.

I set a checkpoint and then reset it.   I tried resetting through a static class, in a test fixture and through an abstract class implemented by the test class and also in the test itself, both before and after my tests and in all cases, it wipes the whole database.

The connection string that I use to create an event is the same I use to reset it and it's a SQL db.

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public async void Should_GetAnEvent(Create.Parameter eventParam)
{
    //Arrange
    var newCheckpoint = new Checkpoint();
    var eventId = await CreateEvent(eventParam);

    //Act
    var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetEventRequest(eventId));

    //Assert
    //Some asserts here
    await newCheckpoint.Reset(ConnectionString.Value.ConnectionString);
}
```

I expected the checkpoint to save a snapshot of the database, so to speak, and then be able to revert to it.  Instead it is wiped entirely.  The test passes.

Comment: Have you tried passing a parameter list with `SchemasToInclude` or maybe even just `DatabaseName`?

Comment: I had not! I just tried passing the schema in with `SchemasToInclude` to no avail.  Is there a way to pass `DatabaseName`?

Answer (score 8):

Respawn does not revert to a known snapshot, it wipes it.  This is by design.  I misunderstood what he library does.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently writing a library, which does exactly what you wanted – restores data to its initial state. It's [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed).

Check it out if the issue is somehow still relevant. Library is still in active development phase, but I'm using it for a few of my projects already, works well.

Answer (score 2):

This completely caught me off-guard as well. Respawn does not snapshot, even though the naming 'checkpoint' suggests otherwise. It basically wipes off everything.

Here's the author's reply on the same: https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn/issues/53#issuecomment-459643494